# Reading from an https-URL in java

Tags: java, ssl, https, inputstream, httpsurlconnection

Currently I am trying to write a programm, that gives back an list with the lowest prices of a list of books on booklooker.de. The site itself uses https and I guess, that is the problem.

Code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;

public class Booklooker {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("list.txt"));
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream(new File("result.txt")));

        String book = "";
        while((book = in.readLine()) != null){
            book.replace(' ', '+').replace("ä", "%E4").replace("ö", "%F6").replace("ü", "%FC").replace("ß", "%DF");
            URL link = new URL("https://secure.booklooker.de/app/result.php?sortOrder=preis_total&setMediaType=0&titel="+book);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)link.openConnection();
            BufferedReader site = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            while(true){
                String line = "";
                if((line = site.readLine()) == null){
                    out.print("Error\n");
                    break;
                }
                else if(line.indexOf("&nbsp;&euro;") != -1){
                    int    index   = line.indexOf("&nbsp;&euro;");
                    double price   = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(index-5, index).trim().replace(',', '.'));
                    index          = line.indexOf("&nbsp;&euro;", index+12);
                    double postage = Double.parseDouble(line.substring(index-5, index).trim().replace(',', '.'));
                    out.print(price+postage+"\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
            site.close();
        }
        in.close();
        out.close();
        System.out.println("Finished.");
    }
}
```

And the error given back:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Invalid Http response
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at Booklooker.main(Booklooker.java:16)
```

I don't know what is going wrong exactly, but there seems to be a problem with the HttpsURLConnection. Has anybody got an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your URL is invalid. Remove the trailing ampersand. There is no HTTPS or SSL problem here, otherwise you would have got a different exception.

Comment: Nope, the URL is valid, with and without the trailing ampersand.; In this case, why does the error report say Invalid Http response at HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(Unknown Source)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using https://www.booklooker.de/ (instead of **secure**.booklooker.de)?
When using "secure" you will get a redirect that might be the problem.